# iOS AppDelegate as singleton failed to return same instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, appdelegate

I tried to made my AppDelegate as a singleton and access it through my application like :

**AppDelegate.h**

```
/.../
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

+(AppDelegate*)sharedAppDelegate;

@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import AppDelegate.h
/.../
@implementation AppDelegate

AppDelegate *sharedAppDelegate;

+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedAppDelegate = [[self alloc] init];
    });
      NSLog(@"shared app: %@",sharedAppDelegate)
      return sharedAppDelegate;

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSLog(@"launched app: %@",self);
}
```

**MyClass.m**

```
#import AppDelegate.h
/.../
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"app in myClass: %@",[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]);
}
```

Logs in console:

```
[***]launched app:   <AppDelegate: 0x78757810>
[***]shared app:     <AppDelegate: 0x78f39760>
[***]app in myClass: <AppDelegate: 0x78f39760>
```

Why isn't the launched one the same as the shared one?

Am I not really make AppDelegate a singleton?

Comment: AppDelegate is not singleton, its Application Responder class, which is always in memory, what you are trying to do is incorrect, you can't do self init with AppDelegate. Just use `(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate];` to get its actual memory reference.

Comment: whoa thanks for the simple and clear comment ! guess I'll close this and read more docs ...

Comment: @iphonic where does it come with " its Application Responder class, which is always in memory"? would you refer me to some source or guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `+sharedAppDelegate` you're allocating a new instance of the `AppDelegate` class. What you want, instead, is to capture the instance created for you by `UIApplication` when the app is launched. The easiest way to do this is to use the `sharedApplication` singleton, which already stores the delegate instance:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedAppDelegate {
    return [[UIApplication shareApplication] delegate];
}
```

Comment: same as @iphonic but there you go!